# Proof by induction: $\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{2i-1} > \frac{n+3}{4}$ [SOLVED]

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I need help to proof the following inequality by induction

> $$P(n):\quad\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{2i-1} > \frac{n+3}{4}$$

Here's what I did so far.. Please tell me where I'm wrong or how to continue

First I check $P(1)$ is true,
Then I asume $P(n)$ is true for all Natural numbers $n\leq k$ and want to see if it implies the following statement:

$$P(k+1): \quad\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{1}{2i-1} > \frac{(k+1)+3}{4} $$

So I begin like this

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{1}{2i-1} = \sum_{i=1}^{2^{k}} \frac{1}{2i-1} + \sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{1}{2i-1}$$

Then by induction hypothesis

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k}} \frac{1}{2i-1} + \sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{1}{2i-1}
>\frac{k+3}{4}+\sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{1}{2i-1}$$

> Here is where I'm stuck.
>
> I think that I should prove that
> $$\sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{1}{2i-1} > \frac{1}{4}$$
> That way, I could state that $p(k+1)$ is valid $\forall k \in N$.

Is this the right way to solve it? How should I continue?

Comment: I suspect you mean "I assume $P(n)$ is true for all $n\leq k$".

Comment: In general this seems like the right way to solve it. Note that $\frac{1}{2i-1}>\frac{1}{2^{k+2}}$ for all $2^{k}+1\leq i\leq 2^{k+1}$. That should help finding the next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from where you left,
$$\sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{1}{2i-1} > \frac{1}{4}$$
would imply 
$$\sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{2^{k+2}}{2i-1} > \frac{2^{k+2}}{4}$$
or
$$\sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{2^{k+2}}{2i-1} > 2^{k}$$
which is true since for all $i$, every term on the left will be greater than one, and you'll be summing it up $2^k$ times.